# t.isRestProperty is not a function at DestructuringTransformer.pushObjectPattern

Tags: reactjs, redux, ecmascript-6, destructuring

The code I am trying to execute is as below.

```
const obj = {place: 'kar', number: 45};
const {place, number} = obj;
console.log(place);
```

I get the following error while using ES6 object destructuring.

```
t.isRestProperty is not a function
    at DestructuringTransformer.pushObjectPattern
```

I have updated babel-core, babel-loader, webpack, and @babel/cli

Comment: Define "works fine" because it would definitely behave differently if you removed the two `{}` characters.

Comment: Please edit the question to include additional details.

Comment: thank you loganfsmyth

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue is resolved now. The error was thrown due to the conflicts between the versions of babel-core, babel-loader and babel-cli. Now the issue is resolved after I installed them afresh with following versions.
"dependencies": {
"babel-cli": "6.24.1",
"babel-core": "6.25.0",
"babel-loader": "7.1.1",